# Change font size by Facebook likes

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, ipython, facebook-opengraph

Im trying to create a HTML that is live updating while input from the Facebook data. Is there a way to connect your font sizes (H1 etc.) to the Facebook likes. The more likes they have, the bigger the names. Also trying that is updating when there are changes in the amount of likes.

Big Thanks

Comment: you'll want the font-size css attribute perhaps

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval function, check for the number of likes on your object every n seconds and accordingly update the style of the HTML element:

```
// Will check and update the font size every 5 seconds

setInterval(function {
  FB.api(
    "/{object-id}/likes",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        $("#element").css("font-size", response.total_count + "px");
      }
    }
  );
}, 5000);
```

Of course you need some sort of conversion from total_count to actual font-size, you don't wanna have your font size something like 3667px.

Comment: _"check for the number of likes on your object every n seconds and"_ ... run into the API rate limits quickly.

Comment: Well, in that case, maybe set up a Webhook, have the number updated on your own server and poll the server or use a messaging service.